# Prevent page reload on back button

Tags: wordpress, infinite-scroll

I know there are lot of questions bout this, but they are in different contexts.
I've googled a lot around and couldn't find a solution. I have a WordPress page that uses http://www.infinite-scroll.com/ for pagination. The problem is well known - when user scrolled down till some dynamically loaded content and opens an item, then presses button "Back", the previously loaded content isn't there. I would like the user to have the same loaded content appear with the same scroll position.

One example is this - conleys.de. You can try it - it doesn't manage it through the page url.

What I was interested in - how to make browser cache all the loaded content and load the cached page instead of reloading it on Back button click

Answer (score 0):

For the browser to load a dynamically generated page output purely from history without running the page generation again, this can't easily be achieved without some clever jiggery pokery to determine weather the static content has already been created.

Perhaps this can be done with some clever Browser cookies or session data to direct the "BACK" page to load the local version, as well as page headers stating there is no expiry and page content must be in a static form HTML rather than server side form PHP (as Wordpress is).

BUT to make this determination, the code would need to be dynamic and the javascript that Infinite Scrolling relays on to function would need to very slightly change, as the javascript functions only fire post page creation - rather than *on* page creation.

Overall I think the work involved to achieve what you want is at the very least akin to running around the block in order to avoid stepping over a fairly small puddle on the pavement/sidewalk.

.
.
.

If you want a browser to cache the pages, you write them as static pages, if you want the browser to rememeber the cached pages and not call the in page changes of infinite scrolling, you might as well create the page remotely via PHP or some other form and then the end user can simply call and load a static HTML output page directly rather than via a set of PHP requests.

As well as set the headers, etc...

Comment: i just can't understand how this page does it - conleys.de

Comment: when I looked at the http://www.conleys.de website, it didn't do it and pressing back I had to scroll down (again) to load lower content